# Android : How to get Internet Data Usage per Day or by range of time?

Tags: android, networking

I am trying to get the exact Data Usage per Day , or by Range of Time in Android

however from what I searched, I cannot found anything that could do this

Something that I tried

> **[TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)**
>
> this one will reset all data every time the device is boot, so I
>   couldn't use it

---

> **NetworkPolicyManager**
>
> this one require system permission. So, I can't use it

any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a service that will periodically call `TrafficStats` APIs to get current statistics, and store the results. E.g. the delta between two invocations of `getMobileTxBytes()` is the number of bytes received during that time period.

Of course, if someone just pulls a battery out of their phone, you'll lose statistics since the last invocation of your service. So set the frequency of updates according to your needs (every hour versus every minute).